# JavaScript import HTML file content (target is browser)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, parcel

I am building some JavaScript code using [ParcelJS](https://parceljs.org/), that will output a single `.js` file that will run on a **browser**.

In my project I have an asset directory containing HTML files. I want to import the HTML from those, the same way you would `require()/import` a JS file, and put it into a variable.

Of course, you can't `require()` something that is not `.js/json` etc... My HTML asset files won't be bundled with the build.

My temporary solution is to embed my HTML in JS files and exporting the HTML as string...

```js
module.exports = `<div>Hello World</div>`
```

How can I import content of HTML files at build time ?

Comment: By doing so using a format that *is* supported, or, via some other method such as http.

Comment: Can you elaborate ? Also, I can't load those assets remotely.

Comment: For example, your temporary solution. Any method such that after bundling, the html will simply be a string within the js.

Comment: Maybe related? https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/178

Answer (score -3):

I don't know if I got what do you mean, but I think that `load()` in jQuery will help you:

```
$("body").load("Thefilelocation/file.html");
```

Edit:
So what about `parcel watch index.html`

Comment: In order to do that, the html file would need to be bundled. I can only ouput a .js for my specific case